# How to create our own "dialect" of an existing XML schema

Tags: xml, xsd

At [open flightmaps](http://openflightmap.org) we're working with AIXM 4.5 (an outdated version of the Aeronautical Information Exchange Model) as defined by:

http://www.aixm.aero/schema/4.5/AIXM-Snapshot.xsd

A very simple snapshot file could look as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AIXM-Snapshot xmlns:xsi="http://www.aixm.aero/schema/4.5/AIXM-Snapshot.xsd" version="4.5">
  <Ase>
    <codeClass>C</codeClass>
    (...)
  </Ase>
</AIXM-Snapshot>
```

Until now and for internal use only, we've added our few custom extensions by simply using ad-hoc `xt_`-prefixed elements and attributes:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AIXM-Snapshot xmlns:xsi="http://www.aixm.aero/schema/4.5/AIXM-Snapshot.xsd" version="4.5">
  <Ase xt_hasLayers="false">
    <codeClass>C</codeClass>
    <xt_minScale>250</xt_minScale>
    (...)
  </Ase>
</AIXM-Snapshot>
```

Of course, this doesn't validate against the snapshot XSD anymore.

Due to many reasons, we'll stay on AIXM 4.5 as our base exchange format for the time being. However, we'd like to correctly create our own "dialect" of in order to accomodate our extensions and maybe backport things in a way which allows the resulting XML to be validated against a XSD.

Our goal: An OFMX (open flightmaps exchange) format which is a wrapper around AIXM 4.5 and allows markup such as:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AIXM-Snapshot xmlns:xsi="http://www.aixm.aero/schema/4.5/AIXM-Snapshot.xsd" version="4.5" (...)>
  <OFMX:Authority href="http://whatever.com">
    <Ase OFMX:hasLayers="false">
      <codeClass>C</codeClass>
      <OFMX:minScale>250</OFMX:minScale>
      (...)
    </Ase>
  <OFMX:Authority/>
</AIXM-Snapshot>
```

The above could be reduced to a valid AIXM 4.5 document by simply stripping all `OFMX:`-prefixed elements and attributes.

How should I tackle this? How would a simple `OFMX.xsd` look like and how would it be referenced in the XML document?

Thanks a lot for your hints!

---

@michael-kay

XML schema 1.1 should not be a problem, so you mean something like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://openflightmaps.org" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:defaultOpenContent>
    <xs:any/>
  </xs:defaultOpenContent>
  <xs:element name="Authority">
    <xs:attribute name="href" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:include schemaLocation="AIXM-Snapshot.xsd"/>
</xs:schema>
```

However, there appears to be something missing for the include to work, doesn't it?

And given this approach, would it still be possible to define an `OFMX` namespace to prefix all our added elements and attributes with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to extend a schema depends on the way the schema is written, and in particular whether it is designed with extensibility in mind. This schema doesn't explicitly permit elements to be added in a third party namespace (that is, the schema appears to contain no wildcard elements), but at least all the types like AirspaceAssociationType are global, which means you can (if you choose) define new types that are derived from these by extension. If you go down this route, then your instance documents will have to name the extended type in an xsi:type attribute, which is pretty ugly.

Given what you say about the project and given the way this particular schema is written, I think my preferred approach would be to write an XSLT transformation that creates a variant of AIXM-Features.xsd that either explicitly includes your extensions, or that adds wildcards (xs:any elements) making your extensions valid.

If you're prepared to use XML Schema 1.1 (which would restrict your choice of schema processors) then you could consider defining all these types to have an open content model which allows elements in a third-party namespace to appear after the standard schema-defined elements. That can be done simply by adding an xs:defaultOpenContent element to the schema - you could define a new schema document that contains this declaration and then does an xs:include on the standard AIXM-defined schema.

**UPDATE**

I made a mistake here. Reading the spec again, it seems the `defaultOpenContent` element is scoped to a schema document (module): it only affects `xs:complexType` definitions within the same module, not in included modules. So it looks as if a change to AIXM-Features.xsd is needed after all.

If you do use defaultOpenContent, the `xs:any` element can specify a namespace, and can specify `processContents="strict"`, so you can ensure that the elements you add to the model are validated. Of course you'll also need to ensure that the aggregate schema includes your own element declarations as well as the AIXM-defined ones.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your answer! I'd give the third option a shot and have added how I read your suggestion my original post. Could you comment on the two questions there? Again, big thanks!

Comment: Ah, bummer, I would have preferred a solution without the need to touch the AIXM schema.

Comment: Yes. But maintaining an XSLT script to generate your custom schema from the standard one avoids the problems of actually forking it.

Comment: It's more a license thing: Would have been very elegant to use the AIXM schema as is and then wrap around our delta with our own license.

Comment: I guess the other thing you could try in XSD 1.1 is xs:override. Trouble is, you would be overriding every single type declaration, which basically means you aren't using anything from the original. Sorry: I just don't think this schema is designed for extensibility.

Comment: No big surprise though, one of the arguments for the newer yet totally incompatible versions of AIXM is "better extend-ability". Since a hard fork appears to be the only clean solution, I might just clone, rename and ammend the AIXM 4.5 XSD files directly. They are unlikely to change in the future and even if, `diff` should do the job.